# amazon s3 bucket permission denied

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I create laravel app, that generate and save pdf in my bucket.

But the problem is every file is :

```
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>72EE0E6DB555ADBD</RequestId>
```

What i already try, is

> -> permissions ->
>
> -> Block public access - all off
>
> -> Access Control List -> Public Access -everyone - list, write, read = YES

But anyway when file are uploaded i need to go to path of the file and set permission for it.

How i can set all the files to be visible, permission access - yes ?

Edit:
script for upload file

```
$content = $pdf->download()->getOriginalContent();
Storage::disk('s3')->put($pdfname, $content);
```

Comment: The problem is likely with the code that uploads the file, you need to indicate the permissions the file should have during the upload process. Share (edit the question) the code you are using to upload (but don't share your account id / private keys).

Comment: code is simple, but when i upload file using aws inside bucket i have same issue...  but anyway this is mo code

Comment: Did you edit the JSON policy to allow access ?

Comment: ahh ye.. no i did not, i forgot to create one